# How to connect to a remote MySQL server using C#?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a C# Application which would access a MySQL server on another computer. I am trying to do it via IP. Here is my Connection String :

```
server = "192.168.10.221";
database = "restaurantdb";
uid = "root";
password = "";
string connectionString;
connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + "; PORT = 3306 ;" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
mycon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
```

Now the idea is, I would connect it through the Internet or Wi-Fi connection on which both of the computers are connected to. I would then access the database through SQL Strings coded on C#. Now I could also connect them through LAN networking but I don't know how.

I am getting this exception in my code

```
{"Access denied for user 'root'@'Crave-PC.lan' (using password: NO)"}   System.Exception {MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException}
```

Any ideas how I can access the server through networking?

Comment: You sure your password is not wrong? It does connect, though you get access denied error so there is probably something wrong with your credentials, like it says. Maybe root is only allowed to login from localhost. Create a user who has access remotely.

Comment: How do I create a host that has access remotely? I have workbench installed

Comment: I also have a user here named 'root' and has no password

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is at MySQL Server side, root user doesn't have permissions to connect remotelly.
To give root user permisions to connect remotelly just type this on a mysql command line:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@"%" IDENTIFIED BY 'rootPass';
```

Just change 'rootPass' for your current root password, if root doesnt have password MySQL wont let you connect so you will have to define one for it.

One side note: **As a security best practice you should define a different user other than root to access your mysql databases from client applications.**

Hope it helps,

Comment: im using xampp. how can i access that mysql command line if i am using phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 3):

One addition to this thread:

In some cases where two computers are connected to the same network, the connection string defined above might still not work despite the configuration of the source computer and grant of the privileges for the user from the client computer.

In such cases, please consider (before moving further and taking more serious action on source computer such as the modification of Mysql config file etc.) to "use the computer name as the server name instead of the IP address".

i.e.

- first, grant the privileges to the user as described above,
- but
  instead of the connection string proposed above, try the following
  connection string:

so, the connection string would look like:

```
server = "pc-name-whateveritis";
database = "restaurantdb";
uid = "root";
password = "";
string connectionString;
connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + "; PORT = 3306 ;" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
mycon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
```

The name of the source computer might work in many cases the IP address of the source computer returns error.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Changing from root to a different username and set the password works well for remote access because root only have full access privileges when you are on localhost. On a local area network using an IP address gives an error so use the computer name.